# How can I convert matrix<double> to Matrix<float>?

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I want to calculate something like:  `Matrix<float> * Matrix<double>`

the `Matrix<float>` has about 6M*3 elements , how can I convert the `Matrix<double>` to `Matrix<float>` so that I can get a `Matrix<float>` result.

Comment: How big is "very big", and is created a copy of the original `Matrix<float>` (but using `double` values) prohibitively slow/memory-hungry? (If you haven't at last tried that, that seems like the simplest option...)

Comment: And why can't the result Matrix be a Matrix<double>?

Comment: this  matrix<float> have around  6M * 3  elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your double matrix argument to a float matrix using the `Map` function:

```
Matrix<double> m1 = Matrix<double>.Build.Random(6000000,3);
Matrix<float> m2 = m1.Map(x => (float)x);
```

Or alternatively

```
Matrix<float> m2 = m1.Map(Convert.ToSingle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to convert an array of double to an array of float, then you just need to convert your matrix to array and vice versa

```
public static float[][] Convert(double[][] mtx)
{
    var floatMtx = new float[mtx.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < mtx.Length; i++)
    {
        floatMtx[i] = new float[mtx[i].Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < mtx[i].Length; j++)
            floatMtx[i][j] = (float)mtx[i][j];
    }
    return floatMtx;
}
Or:

public static float[][] Convert(double[][] mtx)
{
    return mtx.Select(i => i.Select(j => (float)j).ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```